# CSS transition won't start on blur screen

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-transitions, transition

I'm using react js.
I try to run the simple code:

```js
setTimeout(() => {
       setTimeout(() => {
         const element = document.getElementById(‘circle’)
         element.style.backgroundColor = ‘red’
       }, 3000)
     }, 3000)
```

The CSS of 'circle' is just:

```css
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
border-radius: 50%;
background-color: blue;
transition: background-color 2s;
```

I run the code and immediate change tab or minimize the screen, waiting more then 6 seconds and go back to the page and then the transition start. For some reason the transition not run if screen not in focus.
Any help guys???

Comment: Hi Nir, on asking a question please provide a producible example, [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Side note: querying the DOM in react is often a bad practice, meaning - you may doing something wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make setInterval also work when a tab is inactive in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927284/how-can-i-make-setinterval-also-work-when-a-tab-is-inactive-in-chrome)

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you describe depending on the browser [because inactive tabs have low priority execution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5927432/7882470).

While you performing a "JS Animation" you may want to use [`requestAnimation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame).

A better approach may use a "CSS Animation" with [`transition-delay`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-delay).

Comment: Thanks for answer, i will try it soon.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code why are using Apostrophe mark in code.

```
    <script>
        setTimeout(() => {
               setTimeout(() => {
                 const element = document.getElementById('circle')
                 element.style.backgroundColor = 'red'
               }, 3000)
             }, 3000)
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is not really help me.
The solution i made is to listen to 'focus' and 'blur' and stop any animations process and timers on blur and continue from last point at focus.